# Php error issue in while loop

Tags: php

I've a SMS Api which send sms(not email) to my client with php. Now I'm trying to send sms from .txt file where all contact number exist:

**My .txt file**

```
shibbir, 8801678877639
babu, 8801534552503
```

**So my while loop is look like this:**

```
$file_handle = fopen("$file", "r");
while ( !feof( $file_handle ) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $line_of_text[1] ."<BR>";       
    $obj = new Sender("myservername","myport","username","password","$sender", "$msg", 
"$line_of_text","2","1"); 
    $obj->Submit();     
    echo "<div class='success'>Successfully sent your message to " . $line_of_text[1] . " Thank 
    You.</div>";
}
fclose( $file_handle );
```

**But I get following error message:**

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\Software Installed\xampp\htdocs\evan\toplevel
\bulksms.php on line 108

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\Software Installed\xampp\htdocs\evan\toplevel\bulksms.php on 
line 106

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\Software Installed\xampp\htdocs\evan\toplevel\bulksms.php on 
line 107
```

My final goal is, User can send sms by uploading .txt file where all contact number exit. So once it's submit the form then sms must be send to those contact number's.

1. Can you guys tell me why i get error message ?
2. And it's show 2 Success confirmation but i want it's must be show 1 success confirmation.

Thanks.

Comment: These are not errors. They're notices. Also they point to specific line in code. How this code looks like? Which line is it?

Comment: what is the output of var_dump($line_of_text); ?

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha Output is : array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "shibbir" [1]=> string(14) " 8801671133639" } AND array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "babu" [1]=> string(14) " 8801534552503" }

Comment: fgetcsv returns an array, you cant then just add the <br> to it like you have

Comment: Is it working if you remove the statement $line_of_text[1] ."<BR>";  from the code?

Comment: @Dagon I don't understand your point.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha I'm doing it.

Comment: @Alex, if now errors, try my answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$file_handle = fopen("$file", "r");
$success_number = array();
    while ( !feof( $file_handle ) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        $success_number[]=$line_of_text[1]; //call this statement if msg sent successfully.
        $line_of_text  = implode(',',$line_of_text ); // i think we need to pass string to the api.
        $obj = new Sender("myservername","myport","username","password","$sender", "$msg", 
    "$line_of_text","2","1"); 
        $obj->Submit();     
    }
    echo "<div class='success'>Successfully sent your message to ".implode(',',$success_number) ."<BR> Thank You.</div>";
    fclose( $file_handle );
```

**MY TEST**

my.txt

```
shibbir, 8801678877639
babu, 8801534552503
```

my.php (removed the call to api)

```
    <?php
    $file = "my.txt";
    $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $success_number = array();
    while ( !feof( $file_handle ) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);    
        $success_number[]=$line_of_text[1]; //call this statement if msg sent successfully.
    }
    fclose( $file_handle );
    echo "<div class='success'>Successfully sent your message to " . implode(',',$success_number) ."<BR> Thank You.</div>";
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
    Successfully sent your message to 8801678877639, 8801534552503
Thank You.
```

Comment: Again, this will print the message 2 times which the OP does not want.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, yes it will print two times since their is two lines of text in the file

Comment: @Alex, let me test this in my local host.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha, Now I don't get any error message but it's not sending SMS. You know if i want to send multiple sms then i've put comma(,) after one number like: 8801671144528, 8801547744854. So now is it the problem ? If so what can i do in my $Obj-> ?

Comment: @Alex, it will work I tested in localhost. got the output as
Successfully sent your message to 8801678877639
Thank You.
Successfully sent your message to 8801534552503
Thank You.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha, Well, It's now showing 2 success message. So If i have 100 number then it will be show 100 success message. Right ? Is there any way to show Only 1 success message with all numbers ?

Comment: Use implode with comma and send to the API

Comment: Put success message outside the loop for displaying once

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha I'm asking to show 1 Success message with all numbers. Is it possible ?

Comment: Ys its possible. Check above comment

Comment: Well, I know if i put success message outside the loop but how it's show all numbers ?

Comment: no you have to build an array of success numbers inside the loop, wait i'll show an example.

Comment: Now i put success message outside of while loop It's show == Successfully sent your message to Thank You.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha, GREAT, JUST GREAT. It's showing me..Successfully sent your message to 8801675588639,8801535884503,, Thank You. I saw the double comma after last number.

Answer (score 1):

try changing your code into this

```
$file_handle = fopen("$file", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
$line_of_text[1]=$line_of_text[1] ."<BR>";       
$obj = new Sender("myservername","myport","username","password","$sender", "$msg", 
$line_of_text[1],"2","1"); 
$obj->Submit();     
echo "<div class='success'>Successfully sent your message to " . $line_of_text[1] . " Thank 
You.</div>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Can you guys tell me why i get error message ? 
> 2) And it's show 2
>   Success confirmation but i want it's must be show 1 success
>   confirmation.

1. They are **not** errors.
2. Move the **`echo`** DIV tag out of your **`while`** loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
$line_of_text[1] ."<BR>";
```

It should be :

```
$line_of_text[1] .= "<BR>";
```

and also your message is inside your loop , so it will be echoed more than once.

This task can be done easily using `file()` and `explode()`